# Inverse of a tedious polynomial function at a specific point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $$y=x^5+x^3+x+1$$ What is $f^{-1}(-41)$ if the function is one-to-one?

Okay, so I'm going to assume that finding the inverse of a polynomial would be tedious and I could try to do it algebraically but it would be messy and pointless. I'm rusty on my algebra so I'm trying to touch up here, but I think this logic does apply:

$f(0)= 1$ and $f^{-1}(1) = 0$
$f(1)= 4$ and $f^{-1}(4) = 1$

Given this, how can I use this to find $f^{-1}(-41)$? Am I even right in my approach?

Comment: That logic is correct. Simply plug in numbers until you eventually find an x such that y = -41. That x is $f^{-1}(-41)$.
It wasn't hard to find that x = -2

Comment: Not too fond of trial and error in mathematics, figured there was a more definitive way. Thanks though

Comment: The given function is for sure one-to-one since its derivative, $5x^4+3x^2+1$, is always positive, due to the fact that $5u^2-3u+1$ has a negative discriminant. So $f(-2)=-41$ is enough to state $f^{-1}(-41)=-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method is to factorize
$$
g(x)=f(x)+41=x^5+x^3+x+1+41=(x+2)(x^4 - 2x^3 + 5x^2 - 10x + 21)
$$
Hence $x=f^{-1}(-41)$ says that $g(x)=f(x)+41=0$, and we see that $x=-2$, or
$x$ is a root of $x^4 - 2x^3 + 5x^2 - 10x + 21$. This is, at least, not "trial and error", see above.

Comment: How'd you find the root?

Comment: By [factorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials) the polynomial $x^5+x^3+x+42$.

Comment: Did you do that by trial and error?

Comment: No, by applying a factorization algorithm, see the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct. Trial and error is kind of a disappointing way to do things, but in this case it seems necessary. Just recognize patterns like if you input a negative number for $x$, you'll get a negative $y$, and then it should be fairly simple to find a pair where $y=-41$.

EDIT: This is not the only way to do it, only one of the possible ways, as mentioned above.

Comment: No, it is not necessary to use trial and error.